# connection to postgres database fails somewhat frequently

Tags: django, database, windows, postgresql

I am connecting to a Postgres database on windows using Django/Pycharm. I have done this plenty of times on other computers and am pretty confident I configured the connection correctly.

Every once in a while the database connection fails and returns an error. It happens both in my Django app as well as using the pycharm UI. It is odd because it works at least every 9/10 times I interact with the database, but I've noticed that *maybe* it usually happens when I try to interact with the db multiple times in quick bursts, but this is not always the case.

In the pycharm database connection UI, when I test the connection it *usually* works, but sometimes fails. I am using the default 'postgres' user, and I suspect that may be the issue.

The following is the db configuration in my Django app, though I'm pretty positive this problem is unrelated to my code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'contract_directory_site',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
    }
}
```

Everything except the password is exactly how it looks in my code and in my PyCharm database connection properties.

The error I get from Django:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

It is pretty much guaranteed to occur after making 10 requests or less, and it has happened on the first try. Here is the entire stack trace:

```
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/fbgnew/PycharmProjects/fbg/procurematch_era/directory_site\listings\views.py", line 44, in listing_search
    return render(request, 'listings/search_results.html', context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 173, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 874, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\fbgnew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

[24/Oct/2017 16:08:14] "POST /home/ HTTP/1.1" 500 180346
```

It also may be worth noting I had some trouble installing postgres. For some reason I could not get the command line tool working, I'm assuming my PATH is messed up, but I'm on a tight deadline and as long as the database works I will figure out the CLI later.

Comment: What is the error you get? What error are you seeing in the postgres logs?

Comment: How do I find the postgres logs? Just restarted PC, I will post the Django/pycharm error I get in a moment.

Comment: Hi @RyanGedwill, did you ever find a solution to this issue?